# Print text obtained after swapping keyboard keys

Tags: java, algorithm

## Problem:

Andi and Bob were friends since childhood days. But, as they grew up Bob started behaving weird and this used to irritate Andi. Once, while Andi took a break after typing a large program Bob came from nowhere and swapped some alphabet keys on Andi's keyboard.

Andi got very angry on seeing this and decided to end their friendship once forever. As we all know Bob is very good at heart and never does anything wrong intentionally. He decided to type the remaining program with the same keyboard Configuration. Given the original fragment of the code that Bob needs to type, You need to tell Bob the code that he should type to get the original code as output.

Help him saving his friendship with Andi.

INPUT :

First line of the input contains a single integer N denoting the number of swaps done by Bob. Next N lines contain a pair of characters A,B denoting the characters which are swapped by Bob (Note that Bob performs these swaps in the given order). From the very next line of input the remaining fragment of the code starts and ends with an end of file character.

OUTPUT:

print the fragment of the program that Bob types.

CONSTRAINTS:

1 <= N <= 106

1 <= |length of codefragment| <= 106

code fragment contains uppercase and lowercase english alphabets only and space.

A,B belongs to Alphabet set (both upper case and lower case letters are included).

## My Approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        String[] from = new String[N];
        String[] to = new String[N];
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            from[i] = s.next();
            to[i] = s.next();
            map.put(from[i], to[i]);
        }
        String str = s.next();

        for (String st : map.keySet()) {
                str = str.replace(st, "*").replace(map.get(st), st)
                        .replace("*", map.get(st));
        }
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```

I don't know why, my answer is not correct. What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What input are you giving and what output are you getting that tells you that something's wrong? Please be way, way more specific.

Comment: @musical_coder I was submitting this solution on programming site. After submission, I'm getting wrong answer message. They don't show the test cases which failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is my code in Java. Which solves basic inputs and work for 2 input cases.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class CharacterSwapping {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Character> orgnlAlphabets = new ArrayList<Character> ();
        orgnlAlphabets.add('A');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('B');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('C');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('D');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('E');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('F');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('G');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('H');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('I');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('J');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('K');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('L');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('M');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('N');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('O');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('P');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('Q');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('R');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('S');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('T');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('U');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('V');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('W');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('X');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('Y');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('Z');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('a');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('b');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('c');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('d');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('e');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('f');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('g');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('h');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('i');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('j');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('k');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('l');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('m');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('n');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('o');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('p');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('q');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('r');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('s');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('t');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('u');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('v');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('w');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('x');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('y');
        orgnlAlphabets.add('z');
        ArrayList<Character> swappedAlphabets = new ArrayList<Character> ();
        swappedAlphabets.addAll(orgnlAlphabets);

        try {
            //BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/tmp/characterswapping_input.txt"));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            ArrayList<String> inputs = new ArrayList<String> ();
            String sCurrentLine;
            int glbLineCnt = 0;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null && !"".equals(sCurrentLine.trim())) {
                inputs.add(sCurrentLine.trim());
            }
            glbLineCnt = 0;
            sCurrentLine = inputs.get(glbLineCnt++);            
            int noOfSwapes = Integer.parseInt(sCurrentLine);
            while (noOfSwapes > 0) {
                sCurrentLine = inputs.get(glbLineCnt++);
                String firstLine[] = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                int firstCharIndex = swappedAlphabets.indexOf(firstLine[0].charAt(0));
                int secondCharIndex = swappedAlphabets.indexOf(firstLine[1].charAt(0));
                swappedAlphabets.set(firstCharIndex, firstLine[1].charAt(0));
                swappedAlphabets.set(secondCharIndex, firstLine[0].charAt(0));
                noOfSwapes--;
            }
            sCurrentLine = inputs.get(glbLineCnt++);
            Character currentChar, orgnlChar;
            for (int i = 0; i < sCurrentLine.length(); i++) {
                currentChar = sCurrentLine.charAt(i);
                if (" ".equals(currentChar.toString())) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } else {
                    orgnlChar = orgnlAlphabets.get(swappedAlphabets.indexOf(currentChar));
                    System.out.print(orgnlChar);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It is working for sample input as

```
1
W H
WelloHorld
```

And gives correct output as

```
HelloWorld
```

It also works fine for other inputs
e.g.

```
1
A B
B C

it gives output as 
A C
```

But that coding site says, your code is not working on every case. So not sure for which case this code will fail.